# Any idea about this Beamer theme?

Tags: beamer, lyx

Which Beamer theme is used in this [presentation](http://videolectures.net/site/normal_dl/tag=11005/ratsch_gunnar_lecture1.pdf)?
How I can use this theme in LyX?

Comment: Have you browsed through the manual, to see if there is anything similar there? Oh, and [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: Thanks. now I got it but still I am looking that how to edit the footnote of the main slide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\usetheme[secheader]{Madrid}
```

You can browse the `beamer` manual or go through the [Beamer Theme Matrix](http://www.hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/)

Comment: Thanks! I found it. Would it be possible to edit the footnote. I want to change the name and the short title?

Comment: @biostat: of course, feel free to open a new question, since this one seems to be solved.